# How to delete an item from json while iterating it?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I cannot delete items from json while iterating it. I've tried several ways to achieve it, but it's not working as expected.

There is json example:

```
{
    "year" : 2019,
    "values" : [{
            "key" : 70,
            "messages" : [{
                    "code" : 997,
                    "messages" : 1112245
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "key" : 90,
            "messages" : [{
                    "code" : 997,
                    "messages" : 26347680
                }
            ]
        }
]}
```

I need to iterate "values" and delete the items with specific "key". 
There is a separate list of keys:

`key_list = [60, 70, 80, 90]`

I tried to use following code, but it doesn't work:

```
for i in json["values"]:
        if i["key"] not in key_list :
            del i
```

I also tried to use pop, popitem, clear without effect.

The current version is:

```
def delRecords(json):
    x = 0
    for i in json["values"]:
        if i["key"] not in key_list :
            json["mtids"].pop(x)
        x += 1
    return json
```

But it looks ugly and I have to start the script several times to delete all items. 
Could you please give an advice how can I delete the items from the json? Is there any best practice for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No hackery is needed if you iterate in reverse and delete:

```
key_set = {60, 70, 80, 90}  
values = jsonData['values'] # hold reference, less typing  

for i in reversed(range(len(values))):
    if values[i]['key'] not in key_list:
        del values[i]
```

Or, you may use a list comprehension to re-create the list if your data is reasonably sized:

```
jsonData['values'] = [d for d in jsonData['values'] if d['key'] in key_set]
```

PS, use a set when checking for keys because set lookup is constant time.